# Amplitude demodulation on receiver receiving higher frequency than initial message tone

Tags: frequency, receiver, amplitude-modulation

I'm using an envelope detector to demodulate my AM signal with the schematic below. 
[image]

I'm expecting to hear a 1Khz tone at V_demod but when I listen in on the signal, the frequency of V_demod in real life sounds higher in pitch compared to 1kHz. Does this mean I have a bit of Frequency Modulation? Can this also be the result of not having the circuit closely tuned to the specific carrier frequency? I thought if the circuit isn't tuned very closely to the carrier frequency, I would get a bunch of static and the amplitude will drop (like how if you tune an AM radio slightly outside of the frequency, you get this kind of response)

Comment: Are you certain that the RF signal source modulator is correctly configured? For example, a 1 kHz sine wave without a DC offset will produce double sideband suppressed carrier - your demodulator will produce 2 kHz + harmonics.

Comment: @glen_geek No, double sideband does not imply a doubling of frequency when received by an AM envelope detector.  Harmonic distortion could, but that is a different issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've been bitten by AM modulators that produce no carrier when Vmod = 0V (a +ve or -ve DC offset produces carrier). Perhaps my description of suppressed-carrier AM is missing something? I could outline the scenario with SPICE graphs in an answer.

Comment: A proper AM modulator *always* emits carrier.  Otherwise it is over modulated.  If the signal lacks a carrier then a different detection scheme is needed, for example a synchronous or product detector (ie, "BFO" in hamspeak).  But it still won't double the audio frequencies, unless grossly mistuned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RC time constant appears to be too long for envelope detecting a 1 kHz sine waveform correctly. This will produce audible harmonics and may give the impression that the tone is higher pitch: -

[image]

470 kohm and 1 nF produce a 3 dB cut-off of 339 Hz. Try lowering the 470 kohm to something like 47 kohm.

Fix this first then see what happens.

Comment: I've fixed the RC value but I still find that I can hear audible harmonics. I wonder if its due to the fact that my carrier frequency and my audio frequency isn't separated by a large amount, (carrier frequency ~40kHz and audio frequency ~1kHz)

Comment: In fact what I'm currently observing is the carrier wave becomes a triangular or a sawtooth wave at the output of my demodulating circuit

Comment: I would recommend using a fast diode and resistor then using a sallen key op-amp low pass filter to extract reasonably distortionless audio in that case.

Comment: I'm currently using a 1N4148, isn't that a fast diode by nature where they can be used in switching applications up to about 100 MHz with a reverse-recovery time of no more than 4 ns

Comment: @GuyLee The diode is fine - it's your filtering that is compromised by having carrier and modulator only 40:1 apart. You need a better filter and that is why I recommended an op-amp type. Have you got any questions about this answer I gave: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/313215/am-amplitude-modulation-colpitts

Comment: I don't have any questions for that answer. It was what I needed. Marked as accepted solution.